# No changes in the Admin or the Api although Migrations are done successfully

Tags: python, django, api, migration, migrate

I have pushed a Django project to a droplet and migrated my app. Migrations were done successfully. Then, I created a user and all the models appeared in the Admin. Later, I added a property to one of my models locally, then pushed the changes and pulled them on the server. Finally, I made migrations again, but this time the added property, although the changes were migrated successfully, did not appear in the admin or the API. I restarted the server many times, but that did not help.

That's what I got when I ran the following two commands.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Migrations for 'courses':
  courses/migrations/0002_exam_course_name.py

- Add field course_name to exam

command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Operations to perform:

```
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, courses, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying courses.0002_exam_course_name... OK
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04), I should run:

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

Every time I make changes to my Django App.